# Cleaning Varchar data in SQL Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-cleaning

I'm trying to clean some varchar data on Snowflake and having some issues on this column - I'd like all data where information is missing to display as null, rather than eg. 'unknown'. The data looks like this:

```
+---------------------------+
| Entity                    |
+---------------------------+
| Walgreens                 |
+---------------------------+
| Apple                     |
+---------------------------+
| Microsoft                 |
+---------------------------+
| 2018 Quora hack           |
+---------------------------+
| Unknown government agency |
+---------------------------+
| Unknown                   |
+---------------------------+
```

And I'd like to standardised it, either by changing the original column or adding a revised ones, so it looks like this:

```
+-----------+
| Entity    |
+-----------+
| Walgreens |
+-----------+
| Apple     |
+-----------+
| Microsoft |
+-----------+
| Quora     |
+-----------+
| null      |
+-----------+
| null      |
+-----------+
```

Here's what I've tried so far. The plan was to find something that would work for the 'Unknown' bits of data and then apply it to more specific cases like simplifying the '2018 Quora hack.'

1

```
select *
from data_breaches
order by case when "Entity" like '%nknown%'
then NULL else "Entity" end
```

This returned the data, but put entities which said 'Unknown' in them at the end of the table and didn't change them to `null`

2

```
select "Sector", "Records Number", "Method"
if "Entity" IN('Unknown'), NULL, "Entity") as Enclean
from data_breaches
```

Returned this error:  `Syntax error: unexpected '"Entity"'. (line 2)`

I think maybe Snowflake doesn't support this syntax?

3

```
select "Year", "Records", "Organization type","Method"
iff("Entity" like '%nknown', NULL,"Entity")
from data_breaches
```

Returned this error: `Syntax error: unexpected '('. (line 2)`

Comment: The first step is to formulate the rules precisely. Rule #1 may be: select a NULL for every string that contains the word UNKNOWN at whatever position and regardless of upper/lower case. Is this the rule you want? Or must the string begin with the word? Must it be 'Unknown' or 'unknown', but not 'UNKNOWN'? Give us the exact rule. And what is rule #2 that you want to apply on such strings as '2018 Quora hack'?

Comment: As to the syntax: You have shown how to select the entity or null in your first query, but instead of selecting it you order by it. And in your other queries you are suddenly using `if` and `iff` although the first query already shows that your `CASE` expression does work just fine. So why don't you use it in your `SELECT` clause?

Comment: As to the syntax errors: there is a comma missing after "Method".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ILIKE` and `CASE` expression to handle `Unknown` inside column:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT Entity ILIKE '%Unknown%' THEN Entity END AS Entity
FROM data_breaches;
```